# Redirect in Angularjs Ionic

Tags: angularjs, redirect, ionic-framework, reload

Redirect using `$state.go()` in **Angularjs** Ionic with reload the page.

This is the code:

```
$state.go("app.orang");
```

That's work but not reload the page, how to also reload the page?

Comment: you have cache view set to `true` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience when working with ionic. when you want to redirect and reload page. You should call "$scope.apply()" to apply new value to view. I think it help for you.

Comment: can you give the example with my code, because i don't know how to use that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Caching can be disabled and enabled in multiple ways. By default,
>   Ionic will cache a maximum of 10 views

[ion-nav-view - Caching](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/)
 - you can disable cache globally, within state provider, or with ion-view attribute:

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="My Title!">
```

Comment: that's make my view blank

Comment: by adding cache-view="false" to your own respective ion-view now page becomes blank?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your controllers logic inside

```
.controller('NewPageCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
    //Your redirected new pages logic inside this 
  })
})
```